# I want to transfer text from one text field to another. Like first text field to second text field, second to third, third to first in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: function, button, textarea

```
<body>
   <button onclick="movebtn()">Click to move</button><br>
   <textarea name="txt" id="ptextone" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
   <textarea name="txt" id="ptexttwo" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
   <textarea name="txt" id="ptextthree" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
</body>
```

this is my code and  want JavaScript function to move text from on text area to other on click function.

Comment: What's the concept? Does this have to happen at one time for all textareas, or does it have its own effect for each textarea?

Comment: firstly i will enter the text in first text area. then on click button the text should move from first text area to second text area. then again on click text should move from second to third. then  again on click third to first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second solution.

```
var arr=['ptextone','ptexttwo','ptextthree'];
var i=0;
function movebtn(){
mt = document.getElementById(arr[i]).value;
document.getElementById(arr[i]).value = "";

    if(i == 0){
       document.getElementById(arr[1]).value = mt;
       i++; 
    }else if(i ==1){
        document.getElementById(arr[2]).value = mt;
        i++;
    }else if(i ==2){
        document.getElementById(arr[0]).value = mt;
        i=0;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first answer for the question. but want to know whether there is another effective solution for this question.

```
<html>
  <body>
     <button onclick="movebtn()">Click to move</button><br>
     <textarea name="txt" id="ptextone" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
     <textarea name="txt" id="ptexttwo" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
     <textarea name="txt" id="ptextthree" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  </body>
</html>

var arr=['ptextone','ptexttwo','ptextthree'];
var i=0;
 function movebtn(){
    mt = document.getElementById(arr[i]).value;
    document.getElementById(arr[i]).value = "";

        for(i;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
            if(i == 2){
                i=0;
                document.getElementById(arr[i]).value = mt;
                break;
            }
            else if(i <arr.length-1){
                i++;
                document.getElementById(arr[i]).value = mt;
                break;
            }
        } 
 }
```